# Waiting for other function to end in constructor function

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have this type of constructor of `Child`. Function play has to decrement hunger and increment fun after every second for the time, that is put as a parameter. If either the fun is 10 or the hunger is 1, it has to stop.
Function `need` has to return CURRENT fun and hunger. I have a problem how to do it if I want to wait for `play()` if there is any pending, like in my code. Could you help?
Parameter in `play` determines how many seconds the child plays - so e.g. if there is 3, the fun will increase +3

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, type, hunger) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.type = type;
    this.hunger = hunger;
}

function Child(firstName, lastName, age, type, hunger) {
    Person.call(this, firstName, lastName, age, type, hunger)
    this.fun = 5
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child

    Child.prototype.play = async function (sec) {

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.fun >= 10 || this.hunger <= 1) {
            clearInterval(interval)
        } else {
            this.fun += 1
            this.hunger -= 1
        }
    }, 1000)

        setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), sec * 1000)
}
Child.prototype.need = async function () {
    await this.play()
    return "Fun: " + this.fun + " , hunger: " + this.hunger
}

const child1 = new Child("child1", "childdddd", 3, 'boy', 4)

child1.play(3)

console.log(child1.need())
```

Comment: You can't. JS is single threaded. So you have to either use promises or callbacks

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the constructor function?

Comment: thank you guys, but the answer is below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, but the `async` functions return a `Promise`, so you have to either:

- Provide a callback in `then`
- `await` it

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, type, hunger) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.type = type;
    this.hunger = hunger;
}

function Child(firstName, lastName, age, type, hunger) {
    Person.call(this, firstName, lastName, age, type, hunger)
    this.fun = 5
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)
Child.prototype.constructor = Child

Child.prototype.play = function (sec) {
    this.result = new Promise(resolve => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.fun >= 10 || this.hunger <= 1) {
                end();
            } else {
                this.fun += 1
                this.hunger -= 1
            }
        }, 1000)
        
        setTimeout(end, sec * 1000)
        
        function end() {
            clearInterval(interval)
            resolve()
        }
    })
}
Child.prototype.need = async function () {
    await this.result;
    return "Fun: " + this.fun + " , hunger: " + this.hunger
}

const child1 = new Child("child1", "childdddd", 3, 'boy', 4)

child1.play(3)

child1.need().then(console.log);
```

Comment: If I wanted to await it, what should I do?

Comment: `await child1.need()` but it requires the surrounding function to be declared as `async` or your runtime environment to support top-level `await`

Comment: I see, so it’ll be better to make „then”.

Comment: The two are equivalent it's just a matter of code appearance and also it depends on how you call this code.

Comment: it doesn't work. I mean, it returns Fun and Hunger, but with the values that were given while creating the object. It doesn't return the values that changed after the child1.play(3).

Comment: I've provided the fix, you have to wrap the interval inside a `Promise`, otherwise you can't `await` it

Comment: To be honest it didn't change anything - the result is still the same.

Comment: The result is Fun = 5 + 3 = 8 and hunger  = 4 - 3 = 1 like it should, because the timeout was reached

Comment: I'm sorry, it is working, but why did you make that end() function? Am I not able to put it in each of the statements? Do I have to have that special "end" function?

Comment: I wrapped the `clearInterval` and `resolve` in a single function in order not to repeat the code because it appears in two places

Comment: Yeah, but I tried to repeat it, and it didn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: I don't know either 

Comment: I put under the "if" statement: 
`clearInterval(interval); resolve();`
and inside the `setTimeout(()=> {clearInterval(interval); resolve()}, sec*1000)`

Comment: Also, why doesn't it work if I write inside the `setTimeout` end() - you wrote only end, without ().
I'd send you my code, what I wrote with the repeated code, but in comments it wouldn't look nice.

Comment: I've edited because you had two `play` calls (the `.play()` without parameters was creating a duplicate interval which was being cleared immediately) so I've stored the `Promise` into a result property for further `await`. Also the `() => end` was a mistake I replaced it with `end`

Comment: To be honest, I don’t understand why and where I’m making a duplicate interval.

Comment: Because you have two `play` calls, one at top-level and one inside `need`